Does the Series Converge or Diverge? $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{n!}{n^3})$
I have a question involving the following;
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{n!}{n^3})$
In this problem, I am required to find the convergence based on the Direct Comparison Test.
I would appreciate it if anyone could answer this and tell me what to compare it to.

You can use that $n! \ge n(n-1)$

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

For $n \ge 6$ you have that $\frac{n!}{n^3} \ge 1$.
